How to set maximum cart quantity for a certain product with date range in Magento
I need to specify maximum product quantity to be sold in a cart. I know from previous questions that it can be achieved using attribute inside product configuration. However, I need to set this maximum quantity for a date period with start and end dates? Is this applicable? If yes, how can this be achieved?
